# Getting “Please see the error above” when trying to post an Answer

Tags: support

I had a problem, so I have asked a Question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278153/lines-of-log-files-referenced-by-logwatch-warnings-ubuntu-server-18-04).

Then later on I have found out how to solve it, so I was going to post an Answer.

I was prevented to post the answer with a message: `Please see the error above`, but there was actually nothing highlighted/stated/suggested above or below or anywhere else, regarding the problem.

So, I thought I would ask this Question, why it was so?

Then by trying to post this I found out, that while I was writing the Answer to the original [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278153/lines-of-log-files-referenced-by-logwatch-warnings-ubuntu-server-18-04) the website timed out on me.

It was time to log back in, but I had no idea because the message in the title was all I was getting, without explanation.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This seems like a bug.

Comment: @Zanna --- Hi.. Thanks for moving it, I have been wondering for some time what the place is for topics like the above.

Comment: I am very sorry that meta is not more discoverable. Since the top bar was redesigned, meta has become a secret place :(

Answer (score 1):

So, yes, try to see if you need to **log back in**, that might be why you are getting `Please see the error above` without any explanation or highlight of what the actual problem is.